# How to get the grand total and the subtotal in one row?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is the expected output.

```
ID | GRAND_TOTAL | CHANNEL_1 | CHANNEL_2
1  | 100.00      | 50.00     | 50.00
2  | 500.00      | 100.00    | 400.00
```

But my query resulted like this:

```
ID | GRAND_TOTAL | CHANNEL_1 | CHANNEL_2
1  | 100.00      | 50.00     | 0
2  | 100.00      | 0         | 50.00
1  | 500.00      | 100.00    | 0
2  | 500.00      | 0         | 400.00
```

This is what I tried in my query.

```
SELECT 
       ID, 
       SUM(Amount) AS GRAND_TOTAL,
       CASE WHEN CHANNEL_ID = 1 THEN AMOUNT ELSE 0 END CHANNEL_1,
       CASE WHEN CHANNEL_ID = 2 THEN AMOUNT ELSE 0 END CHANNEL_2
FROM
       CHANNEL_AMOUNT
GROUP BY
       ID, CHANNEL_ID, AMOUNT
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GROUP BY ____` means "I want one result row per ____". You don't want one result row per ID, cannel and amount, but only one per ID. Hence: `GROUP BY id`. Then you want *sums* per channel, so use `SUM`.

```
SELECT
  id,
  SUM(amount) AS grand_total,
  SUM(CASE WHEN channel_id = 1 THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS channel_1,
  SUM(CASE WHEN channel_id = 2 THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS channel_2
FROM channel_amount
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY id;
```

(In standard SQL this would be `SUM(amount) FILTER (WHERE channel_id = 1)`, but SQL Server doesn't feature the filter clause yet, so we use a case expression inside the aggregation function.)

Comment: When I changed the query based on your answer.

The result I'm getting is this:

ID | GRAND_TOTAL | Channel_1 | Channel_2

1 | 100.00                 | 100.00         | 0.00

2 | 500.00                 | 0.00         | 500.00

Comment: @jymskrl, This query works as intended, check [this demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/8lZT2SsW), or maybe you have a different table schema. It would be better if you shared a sample of your input table in your question.

Comment: These are probably the correct figures. In your request you got confused with IDs and amounts. For instance there is an amount of 50 for ID 1 and an amount of 50 for ID 2, but in your desired result, you show these amounts both for ID 1. (I, too, made a demo. It shows your result and mine. You can see it here: https://dbfiddle.uk/kOSUnNTZ.)

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I'm sorry, yes you are correct. The desired results are now showing in my query. Now I get why my first query is not working because of the grouping in the channel Id. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you want grouping by Id only

```
SELECT 
       ID, 
       SUM(Amount) AS GRAND_TOTAL,
       SUM(CASE WHEN CHANNEL_ID = 1 THEN AMOUNT ELSE 0 END) CHANNEL_1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN CHANNEL_ID = 2 THEN AMOUNT ELSE 0 END) CHANNEL_2
FROM
       CHANNEL_AMOUNT
GROUP BY
       ID
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just try GROUP BY ID.

```
SELECT 
   ID, 
   SUM(Amount) AS GRAND_TOTAL,
   CASE WHEN CHANNEL_ID = 1 THEN AMOUNT ELSE 0 END CHANNEL_1,
   CASE WHEN CHANNEL_ID = 2 THEN AMOUNT ELSE 0 END CHANNEL_2
FROM
   CHANNEL_AMOUNT
GROUP BY
   ID
```